# Does IPFS provide block-level file copying feature?

Tags: delta, ipfs

**Update 11-14-2019:**  Please see the following discussion for feature request to IPFS: [git-diff feature: Improve efficiency of IPFS for sharing updated file. Decrease file/block duplication](https://github.com/ipfs/notes/issues/392)

---

There is a `.tar.gz` file, which contains a data.txt file, `file.tar.gz` (~1 GB) stored in my IPFS-repo, which is pulled from another `node-a`.

I open the data.txt file and added a single character in a random locations in the file(beginning of the file, middle of the file, and end of the file), and compress it again as `file.tar.gz` and store it in my IPFS-repo.

When `node-a` wants to re-get the updated `tar.gz` file a re-sync will take place.

I want to know using `IPFS` whether the entire 1 GB of file will be synced or there exists a way by which parts of the file that is changed (called the delta) get synced.

---

Similar question is asked for the `Google Drive`: [Does Google Drive sync entire file again on making small changes?](https://superuser.com/questions/1368892/does-google-drive-sync-entire-file-again-on-making-small-changes)

> The feature you are asking is called "Block-Level File Copying". With
>   this feature, when you make a change to a file, rather than copying
>   the entire file from your hard drive to the cloud server again, only
>   the parts of the file that changed (called the delta) get sent.

As far as I know, `Drobox`, `pCloud`, and `OneDrive`, which however only supports it for Microsoft Office documents, offers block level sync.